# Windows Serice Hosted WCF - Username Authentication

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-client

I've looked at the security guide at wcfsecurity.codeplex.com. The guide is fairly straightforward. However, I cannot find anything relating to  a WCF service hosted in a Windows Service.

Without the support of IIS, ASP.net runtime and all its role, profile, etc providers, is it possible to still apply security to the WCF service??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its absolutely possible to host in a windows service and secure the WCF service. For username authentication you can still use the RoleProvider model if that's what you want to do or you can write a [custom userName validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx)

The WCF model is that all WCF features should be available independently of the hosting environment. The only time this changes if you opt into ASP.NET compatibility mode

**Edit: added wiring in customer role provider config**

To configure user names with a role provider use the following config

```
 <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication membershipProviderName="myCustomRoleProvider"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks Richard.

Comment: Actually, a question Richard: if i were to use the RoleProvider in my windows service, how would i go about doing it? I understand the creation of a custom one.

Comment: You add it in the config via a serviceBehavior. Edited answer to show config

Comment: Yes and specify the new role provider in the System.Web config section